# Como definir una propiedad en otra propiedad

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, desarrollo, sharpdevelop

Mi consulta es si se puede crear clases donde se pueda dividir alguna propiedad, le escribo un ejemplo de una clase que se desea definir:

Clase Registro

Nombre -> tipo cadena

ID -> tipo cadena

Edad -> tipo entero

Trabajo (aqui no se como definir, pero quiero que sea de esta manera)

```
  Area -> tipo cadena

 Sueldo -> tipo entero
```

La idea es al crear la instacia (por ejemplo: RegistroPersona), se puedan accesar las propiedades de la siguiente forma:

RegistroPersona.Nombre

RegistroPersona.ID

RegistroPersona.Edad

RegistroPersona.Trabajo.Area

RegistroPersona.Trabajo.Sueldo

Cualquier ayuda le agradezco de antemano y gracias...

Answer (score 3):

Para eso tienes que declarar dos clases:

```
public class TrabajoPersona 
{
   public string Area {get; set}
   public int Sueldo {get; set;}

}
```

Una vez definida la clase `TrabajoPersona` ya puedes añadir una propiedad de este tipo a la clase `Persona`:

```
public class Persona
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public string Nombre {get; set;}
   public int Edad {get; set;}
   public TrabajoPersona Trabajo {get; set;}
}
```

Luego puedes instanciar un objeto de la clase `Persona`, por ejemplo de la siguiente manera:

```
var p = new Persona {
   Id = 1,
   Nombre = "Jesús López",
   Edad = 62,
   Trabajo = new TrabajoPersona {
      Area = "Desarrollo de softare",
      Sueldo = 100_000
   }
};
```

Y acceder a las propiedades de la siguiente manera:

```
var id = p.Id;
var nombre = p.Nombre;
var edad = p.Edad
var areaTrabajo = p.Trabajo.Area;
var sueldoTrabajo = p.Trabajo.Sueldo;
```

Comment: Gracias, justo lo que necesitaba....

Comment: @LeonardoOliveros en ese caso deberías marcar la respuesta como correcta